# Выборка расписания с сайта - Java

Tags: java, android, jsoup, парсер

Пытаюсь сделать приложение, которое будет парсить страницу с расписанием автобуса и выводить его.

Суть в том, чтобы расписание бралось первой остановки и если автобус будет не раньше, чем текущее время. То есть, если сейчас время 18:10, то надо вывести все оставшееся расписание с 18:10.

http://mybuses.ru/moscow/bus/734/

В идеале был бы показ только 3 автобусов, которые ближе всего к текущему времени.

```
class main extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    String Bus1,Sys_time,wtf;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String table="";
        String time;
        Integer first,second;
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        Integer mHour = date.getHours();
        Integer mMinute = date.getMinutes();
        if(mMinute<10){
            mMinute=date.getMinutes()+10;
        }
        String curr_time=mHour.toString()+":"+mMinute.toString();

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mybuses.ru/moscow/bus/734/").get();
            Element table_site=doc.select("table").get(0);
            Element rows1=table_site.select("tr").get(1);

            Iterator<Element> rowIterator=table_site.select("tr").iterator();
            rowIterator.next();
            Integer str1,str2,str3,str4;

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Element e = doc.select("tr").get(2);
                String e_1=e.attr("class");
                str1=e_1.indexOf("-");
                str2=e_1.indexOf(":");
                str3=e_1.indexOf("-");
                str4 = e_1.indexOf(":");
                first = Integer.parseInt(e_1.substring(str1+1, e_1.indexOf(str1+2)));
                second = Integer.parseInt(e_1.substring(str2+1, e_1.indexOf(str2+2)));

                if (first>=mHour && second>=mMinute) {
                    Element rows=table_site.select("tr").get(1);
                    Element record1=rows.select("td").get(1);
                    Iterator<Element> time1=record1.select("td").iterator();
                    wtf = time1.next().text();
                }
                else {
                    wtf="1232132132";
                }
            }
            Element record2=rows1.select("td").get(6);
            Iterator<Element> time2=record2.select("td").iterator();

            table="Автобус прибудет на Ст. Солнечная в "+wtf+" (через n минут)\nАвтобус прибудет на ГМС3 в "+time2.next().text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bus1=table;
        Sys_time=curr_time;

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        textView.setText("Текущее время: "+Sys_time+"\n\nРасписание автобусов: \n"+Bus1);
    }
}
```

В этом коде ошибка:

> Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=41; regionStart=23; regionLength=-24

в строке

```
first = Integer.parseInt(e_1.substring(str1+1, e_1.indexOf(str1+2)));
```

Как ее можно исправить? В моей задумке было получить время из названия класса на сайте, т.к. в названии класса указано время первой остановки `sh2  columnIsVisible 0-05:26-01-0002-0001`, где `05:26` - время. Попытался вырезать это время и сравнить с текущим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исключение вам английским языком говорит что вы вышли за границы строки.

А теперь попробуем разобрать фрагмент вашего кода.

```
str1 = e_1.indexOf("-");
...
...
first = Integer.parseInt(e_1.substring(str1+1, e_1.indexOf(str1+2)));
```

1. в строке **e_1**  строка для парсинга.
2. в целочисленной переменной **str1** индекс символа *-*
3. в переменную **first** хотим получить целое число, в которое преобразуется строка из двух символов после символа *-*

Тут все понятно. А вот дальше начинается интересное.

`e_1.indexOf(str1+2)` - тут вы пытаетесь найти индекс вхождения в исходную строку символа, который является суммой чисел от индекса str1+2. Т.е. собственно нелогичная и некорректная операция. Думаю что вполне можно заменить это просто нв `str1+3`. +3 - потому что конечный индекс не включается в результат операции.

Т.е. код должен быть.

```
first = Integer.parseInt(e_1.substring(str1+1, str1+3));
```

Аналогично и для получения переменной *second*

Comment: Большое спасибо, только я уже сам разобрался. =)